How to stop livewire from rerendering an element
I have a component and inside this component i have a modal, also inside this modal there's an input which validates on user type and form submit.
But when any of these events happen the modal fades out because of the components rerender.
The code is something like this:
<my-component>
  <modal>
    <input type="text" name="title" wire:model="title" />
  </modal>

  {{-- some content --}}

</my-component>

How can i make the component to just rerender the input and not the modal? (because i want to show validation)
By the way i'm using livewire v3!

Just make this modal as separate component.

You can use wire:ignore.self on the modal, and use wire:model.live on the input.
Ignore
Live updating
